# Create directory with today's date, and moving files to it

Tags: date, mv

I'm writing a script to create a directory named with today's date (yyyy_mm_dd), and then move all files ending in today's date to that directory. Is there a better way to move the files to the directory, as what I've done selects the directory as well.

```
now=$(date '+%Y_%m_%d')
mkdir $now
mv *$now $now/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mv *?"$now" "$now/."
```

will ensure that your just-created directory is not selected for move, by requiring there to be at least one character (`?`) in front of the timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

The `find` command can filter on file types as well as file names.
So I think this will do what you want:

```
now=$(date '+%Y_%m_%d')
find . -name "*$now" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 mv -t $now/
```

though you may need to think about whether there are any oddities in your filenames (such as other directories containing the date string) before running this on a large batch.

Comment: What if there's a directory called `foo$now`? Why do you assume that shouldn't be moved?

Comment: @ terdon Because the question asks how to move files and not the directory in question.  On a natural reading, that means the intention is to exclude all directories, though I can see how you might read it differently.